# Display a view as image in another view ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created a view `jpegImage.cshtml` (not the partial view) and it has `jpegImageController`. Controller has `Index` method, which is writing an image to Output Stream. 
In my main view `testimage.cshtml`, I am calling the `jpegImage` view as `<img src="jpegImage.cshtml" />`, which is not showing any image, while if I call the view by URL like `http://<server>/jpegImage/Index`, it returns the image.

Is there anything I am missing?

Below is my code

```
-----------JpegImageController.cs----------------

public ActionResult JpegImage()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            string s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                s = String.Concat(s, random.Next(10).ToString());
            this.Session["CaptchaImageText"] = s;
            CaptchaImage ci = new CaptchaImage(this.Session["CaptchaImageText"].ToString(),200, 40, "Century Schoolbook");

            this.Response.Clear();
            this.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

            // Write the image to the response stream in JPEG format.
            ci.Image.Save(this.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            // Dispose of the CAPTCHA image object.
            ci.Dispose();
            return View();
        }

CaptchaImage is class which is generating the image

--------------jpegImage.cshtml------------
@Html.BeginForm()

--------testImage.cshtml--------------

< img src="@Url.Content("~/views/JpegImage/JpegImage.cshtml")" alt="Captcha" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your jpegImage.cshtml. It is not necessary and kind of a waste to generate.

Change your **JpegImageController.cs** Action to:

```
public FileResult JpegImage()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        s = String.Concat(s, random.Next(10).ToString());
    Session["CaptchaImageText"] = s;

    using (CaptchaImage ci = new CaptchaImage(Session["CaptchaImageText"].ToString(), 200, 40, "Century Schoolbook"))
    {

        // Write the image to a stream in JPEG format.
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        ci.Image.Save(output, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        return File(output, "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

In **testImage.cshtml** simply use:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("JpegImage")" alt="Captcha" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Views like `jpegImage.cshtml` are not served directly by the web server. That is why your view is not being served when you request it in your image tag:

```
<img src="jpegImage.cshtml" />
```

Instead, views are rendered as the result of an action method returning a `ViewResult`. An action method, in turn, is invoked when you make a request for a URL that is routed to the action method. That is why your request for

```
http://<server>/jpegImage/Index
```

does return the image. In other words, your image tag should be

```
<img src="jpegImage/Index" />
```

(you can probably leave out the "Index" part, as that is probably configured as a default in your route).

By the way, if all you need is for your action to return an image, you don't need to return a `ViewResult` or to have a view (.cshtml file) at all. Consider just returning a `FileResult`:

```
public ActionResult Image(string id)
{
    /* Generate your CaptchaImage and somehow get hold of a stream */
    return base.File(steam, "image/jpeg");
}
```

As I don't know the library you are using for generating the image, I cannot tell you how to get a hold of a `Stream`, but you can probably figure that out yourself.

Comment: JpegImage is both the controller name and Action name, there is no Index() shown. Also for maintainability, I'd suggest using `<img src="@Url.Action("JpegImage")" />` instead of hardcoding the path which may change.

Comment: @arserbin3: Thanks, missed that because the OP states that the .../Index uri does return the image.

Comment: it worked with <img src="~/jpegImage" />. thanks for the reply.